# Data not written into shared memory

Tags: c, multithreading, caching, openmp, cpu

I am debugging a function that writes to an array from multiple threads. As MWE it sets each element  to zero and increments it, till `array[i]` contains `i >> 13`. Each element is only modified by a single thread.

But when another threads reads from the array during the writing, parts of the array are never changed, even if the reading thread does not use the value.

```
void test(int* array, int* backup, int length) 
{
#pragma omp parallel
{
    #pragma omp for schedule(static) 
    for(int i = 0; i<length; i++) {
        #pragma omp atomic write
        array[i] = 0;
        int target = i >> 13;
        int tmp = 0;
        int j = i + 5000000;
        while (array[i] < target) {
            j+=15; if (j >= length) j = 0;
            int r;
            #pragma omp atomic read
            r = array[j];
            tmp += r;
            #pragma omp atomic
            array[i]++;
        }
        backup[i]=array[i] * 10 + (tmp & 1);
    }          
}
}
```

When the function is for example run on an 10 million element array that is initialized with 0xABCD1234 (-1412623820), the 20 elements after `array[1974732]` become `11 -1412623820 -1412623820 -1412623820 -1412623820 -1412623820 -1412623820 -1412623820 -1412623820 -1412623820 -1412623820 -1412623820 -1412623820 -1412623820 -1412623820 -1412623820 -1412623820     241     241     241`. (Never the same affected elements)

However, the unread array `backup[i]/10` always contains the correct values, e.g. 241 for all the above elements.

It seems each processor writes the correct value in its cache and then sometimes forgets to update the main memory. Or perhaps the ram is broken and ignores the write? It is happening on a 64-core AMD Opteron 6272, and the issue is unaffected by gcc's optimization level, more flush/fence instructions, or the atomic pragmas.

Remaining testing code:

```
int gbackup[10000000];
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{

    int length = 10000000;
    int* seq = malloc(length * sizeof(length));
    for (int i=0;i<length;i++) 
        seq[i] = i >> 13;

    for (int a=1;a<500;a++)
    {
        int* par = malloc(length * sizeof(length));
        for (int i=0;i<length;i++)
            par[i] = gbackup[i] =  0xABCD1234; 
        parallel_implementation(par, gbackup, length);
        if (memcmp(seq, par, length*sizeof(int)) != 0)  {     
            printf("\nAborting.\n");
            return -1;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**update:**

Actually it does not seem to have anything to do with the reads. Or perhaps it got worse. Even this fails now and leaves array elements that are unchanged or lower than `i>>13`:

```
void test(int* array, int*, int length) 
{
#pragma omp parallel
{
    #pragma omp for schedule(static) 
    for(int i = 0; i<length; i++) {
        #pragma omp atomic write
        array[i] = 0;
        int target = i >> 13;
        while (array[i] < target) {
            #pragma omp atomic
            array[i]++;
        }   
    }          
}
}
```

Comment: It used to be one pragma, but I wanted to try different things on the threads after the for loop. (like more barriers, but they did not change anything)

Comment: Failed to reproduce an issue on `Intel Core i5-3317U` `gcc-6.3.1` all values are in order with `10000000th` being `1220`. If for some reason you are suspecting hardware try running `memtest86` to exclude memory from the potential causes.

Comment: Please provide the remaining code, compiler commands, and runtime environment necessary to reproduce the issue ([mcve]). What compiler version are you using?

Comment: @Zulan: `gcc -g -O3 -std=c99 -fopenmp` with a  `gcc version 4.8.1 20130909 [gcc-4_8-branch revision 202388] (SUSE Linux)`

Comment: It seems it needs the memory leak in the testing code. When it only allocates one buffer and overrides that one repeatedly, it does not fail

Comment: Can't reproduce on a multi socket Opteron 6274 with 5.4.0. Can you try a more recent gcc version? Also you should check the result of `malloc`, otherwise it's technically UB.

Comment: @Zulan: It also happens with gcc 6.3. Although I had to execute that program three times in a row, before the  issue occured. I let it print the address of the buffer, its like `par == 0x7fe87f859010` or `par == 0x7f61cca4b010`

Comment: You might be missing an `atomic` clause in the while loop condition. To me, it seems that your algorithm is not thread safe. The number of iterations in the while loop may be different to what you get in a sequential execution: you actually have inter-loop data dependences because `array[i]` writes happen before `array[j] : j=i+5E6..target` reads. Using just `atomic` will not solve this ordering restriction. This problem has nothing to do with load/store consistency because OpenMP atomics are sequentially consistent by default (implicitly performs memory fence).

Comment: @tgregory Now the admin has run a memory test for five days, but it has not found any hardware issues  :/

Comment: @JorgeBellón but each while loop only runs on a single thread. That thread increments `array[i]` and compares it to target, without any other thread modifying `array[i]`. How could the number of iterations change?